# Will the little character ever do anything if u drop enough candies in candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've almost dropped 8,000 candies on the ground and he just keeps *nom*ing and I'm just wondering he actually does anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, he will continue to nom the candies. The only thing you can get from throwing candies is a chocolate bar from the chest, and afterwards it is pointless to throw any more candies.

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know. sadly after i posted this i decided to throw away over 4 thousand pieces of candy.

Comment: @BlaikeSavo Ouch :(